# How to join columns in single text with quotation marks, commas and parentheses?

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have the following columns:

```
i   ì
o   ò
e   ě
u   ů
A   Â
z   ź
O   Ō
o   õ
A   À
```

And I would like, through formulas, to create a text only with `SUBSTITUTE(` multiplied by the number of rows in `COLUMN B`, would look like this:

```
SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(
```

And I would also like to merge `COLUMN A` with `COLUMN B` and look like this:

```
,"ì","i"),"ò","o"),"ě","e"),"ů","u"),"Â","A"),"ź","z"),"Ō","O"),"õ","o"),"À","A")
```

And as he added more rows in the `COLUMNS A` and `B`, it would be completed automatically. How could I proceed to resolve each of these issues?

Link to Spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JDOKIO2JncQRLdWR1vWfxcXR5z7IBOUJflNgbdMre7M/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
="="&REPT("SUBSTITUTE("; COUNTA(A:A))
```

and:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(QUERY(IF(A:A<>""; 
 ","&CHAR(34)&A:A&CHAR(34)&","&CHAR(34)&B:B&CHAR(34)&")"; );;999^99)))
```